# How to avoid AppDelegate to access Subview(eg: UILabel) of ViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c

I added `UILabel` in `ViewController`.
Through the below code in `AppDelegate`, I'm able to see the subviews of `ViewController`.

```
UIWindow *mywin=[UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow ;
UIViewController *vc1=mywin.rootViewController;
if (vc1!=nil) {
    NSLog(@"Controllers :%@",vc1);
    NSArray *subviews = [vc1.view subviews];
    if ([subviews count] == 0) NSLog(@"NO"); // COUNT CHECK LINE
    for (UIView *subview in subviews) {
        NSLog(@"1%@", subview);
    }

}
```

Can anyone help in restricting it.
Problem Statement :Suppose user forgot its password of XYZ account, question and answer to reset the password is provided by SDK. From App you can get these question and answer, hack its account.
How to prevent this access.

Comment: If you don't want to access the label, don't write code to access it.

Comment: It's breach. Anyone can access the UItextfield Value, Uilabel name. I'm developing SDK. For that i need to fix it. @rmaddy

Comment: I do not understand your problem. Get rid of the code if you do not want it. It is YOUR app delegate. And `view` is a (public) property of `UIViewController' and has to be. `subviews` is a (public) property of UIView and has to be. What exactly are you not happy with?

Comment: You can't. There is no way to keep a programmer from accessing the subviews. Why is it a problem?

Comment: I'm developing Framework with View. It will be integrated in App. I've no control on AppDelegate.

Comment: You may be able to design your SDK in a way that nobody can access its view controllers from outside when there is not reference path to the view controller. But for doing so you must not use it as rootViewcontroller nor should you add it to the chain of view controllers controlled by a navigation controller. However, as it is a view there will always be a way of accessing your view objects.

Comment: Can you explain further? Is there is a way to restrict it or not?

Comment: @HermannKlecker If the view controller is displayed, its views can be accessed.

Comment: @DeepakPrasad You still haven't explained why you care if a programmer can access a view in your library from their app. It's their app.

Comment: @rmaddy Suppose user forgot its password of XYZ account, question and answer  to reset the password is provided by SDK. From App you can get these question and answer, hack its account.

Comment: @DeepakPrasad OK, that's good info. Update your question with those details and refocus your question on how to prevent that access.